# How do I create an image and run it locally?

Tags: docker, sinatra

I am new to docker and I have looked this up, but none of the guides have made it clear.

I have a basic Sinatra app. In its root directory, I have a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM <my_quay_ruby_image> # Supplied for me by someone else
USER root

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile* /app/

RUN bundle install

COPY . /app/

USER myuser

EXPOSE 9898
```

I also have a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
redis:
  image: <my_quay_redis_server_url> # Supplied for me by someone else

web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - <my_port>
  links:
    - "redis:redis"
  command: bash -c "sleep 10; bundle exec rackup"
```

But what now? I can run my Sinatra app locally by running `bundle exec rackup`, but how can I run it via docker, using the settings above, so that I can test and simulate what it will be like in production?

Comment: I can run it locally by simply using `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 0):

Running the container with docker command:

First, build it:

```
$ docker build -t yourimagename .
```

Then, start it using docker:

```
$ docker run -d \ 
    --name yourcontainername \
    yourimagename \
    bash -c "sleep 10; bundle exec rackup"
```

Using docker-compose. Build & Start it:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
$ docker-compose -d -f docker-compose.yml up
```